# Version control and projects

Tags: git, version-control, github

I am using SourceTree for Github.

Problem is that Netbeans or Visual Studio projects have many unnecessary files and folders that don't need uploaded. Only the `.cpp` and `.java` files need to. I know that I can simply put only those in the folder and push them, but I have to do that everytime, rather than copy the whole projects and work on them in the Repository. Not to mention that whole projects occupy a lot of space.

How can I upload only certain files without needing to copy them in the Repository?

Comment: Can you please describe your folder structure? It's not clear why do you think `.gitignore` will not help.

Comment: It is because I have to move the whole project to another folder(the Repository) instead of working with it in the original folder and uploading just the .cpp or .java files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the files you do not wish to upload to your `.gitignore` file. If the files are already in the repository you will need to delete them manually after adding them to the ignore file.

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/180636/gitignore-file-i-am-brand-new-to-git-and-sourcetree-please-help

http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: Problem is VS and NB projects's files differ. I am aware of the ignore function already, but it's not going to work for whole projects, to ignore everything except my .java and .cpp files.

Comment: You should be able to add both to the ignore file without issue.

Comment: But the .java and .cpp files are INSIDE the project folders.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: I'm not familiar with sourcetree but with git you can make you repository inside the project folder and then ignore any auto-generated files.

Comment: If you need two separate projects, one for VS and one for NB, that checkout right out of the box then you will need two repositories. To combine the two you need to only include files that are common to both and manage the project from there. Normally you do not want to include anything but the source code as each developer may have their own settings for the project.

Comment: Instead of having to move the whole project to another folder(the Repository) I want to work in the original folder and upload just the .cpp or .java files. The purpose was to not move the projects at all from their original locations.

Comment: Then make the repository inside the project folders themselves rather than a level up where you are including the project folder or in another folder you use for the repository. Then when you push and pull you should be able to limit it to just the .cpp and .java files. I know you can do this in git, if you are limited by sourcetree then you may need to switch.

Comment: Didn't know I could make an existing folder as repository. That makes sense, then.